# How trigger function after react context hook updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-context

I'm trying to call a function after the "context hook" from react is updated. Tried the code below:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  [context] = useContext(MyContext);
  
  function updateContext():void {
    context = "someNewContext";
  }
  
  function anotherFunction():void {
    console.log("success!");
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    anotherFunction();
  }, [context]);
  
  return (
    <button onClick={updateContext}>update</button>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: what you mean by the context hook in react getting updated ? . context value in react is an object . And also you not mutate the context value directly as you did in the updateContext method . what are we trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i see what was wrong... First i need a wrapper with `useState`, like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [context, setContext] = useState("initial value");
  const value = { context, setContext };

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={value}>
      <MyComponent />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And then on component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  {context, setContext} = useContext(MyContext);

  function updateContext():void {
    setContext("Some new context");
  }

  function anotherFunction():void {
    console.log("success!");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    anotherFunction();
  }, [context]);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => {updateContext()}}>update</button>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```